# How to connect a flutter mobile app to a rest API in node js which is hosted in heroku?

Tags: flutter, heroku

I have deployed a rest API (nodejs) in Heroku but i want to know how to connect my flutter mobile app with these endpoints.I have looked for solution but i haven't seen anything regarding this.my flutter app is running in my mobile device.Hope any one can give a good solution.

Comment: Have you looked into the flutter http package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

First import [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) do mention that in pubspec,yaml
then
Import convert package if you want to deal with jsondata

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Now you will be creating future functions
for get request:

```
Future<void> getGoodRequest1() async{
    var url = 'your url';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    String data = response.body;
    
    print(jsonDecode(data));
    

  }
```

for post request

```
Future<void> postGoodRequest2() async{

String url = 'your url';
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
// if you want to pass json along with it
    String json = '{"query": "example", "data": "example"}';
    // make POST request
    http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    // check the status code for the result
    print('posted');

  }
```

For more you can refer here [Http flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/http)